# How to compute rotated bounding boxes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

**Edit:** As suggested by percusse's answer, I can use `transform shape` option. My first question is now solved. But although the second bounding box is now locally aligned, it is not correct. In fact, `local bounding box` always computes a *globally* aligned bounding box (green points) and `fit` encloses `north`, `east`,`south`, and `west` anchors of this bounding box.

My question is now: how to compute a `local bounding box` **locally** aligned?

New example (the blue rectangle on the right does not fit the red path):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{
  pt/.style={circle,minimum size=3pt,fill=#1,inner sep=0},
  red pt/.style={pt=red},
  green pt/.style={pt=green},
  every picture/.style={line width=1pt,inner sep=0pt},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=20]
  \draw[gray,line width=.4pt] (0,0) grid (6.5,2.5);
  % first case: fitting some nodes
  \node[red pt] (a) at (.5,.5){};
  \node[red pt] (b) at (.5,2){};
  \node[red pt] (c) at (3,.5){};
  \node[red pt] (d) at (2,2.2){};
  \begin{scope}[transform shape]
    \node[fit=(a)(b)(c)(d),draw=blue]{};
  \end{scope}

  % second case: fitting arbitrary path
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=bb]
    \draw[red] (4,1) to[bend right] (6,1) -- (5,2);
  \end{scope}
  \node[green pt] at (bb.north west){};
  \node[green pt] at (bb.north east){};
  \node[green pt] at (bb.south west){};
  \node[green pt] at (bb.south east){};
  % how to find correct bounding box locally aligned ?
  \begin{scope}[transform shape]
    \node[fit=(bb),draw=blue]{};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Original question:**

I want to compute some bounding boxes. Here is my two cases:

1. to fit some nodes (or coordinates), I can use `fit` library.
2. to fit arbitrary paths, I can use a scope with `local bounding box=bb`.

The following code shows this two cases:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{
  red pt/.style={circle,minimum size=3pt,fill=red,inner sep=0},
  every picture/.style={line width=1pt,inner sep=0pt},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[gray,line width=.4pt] (0,0) grid (6.5,2.5);
  % first case: fitting some nodes
  \node[red pt] (a) at (.5,.5){};
  \node[red pt] (b) at (.5,2){};
  \node[red pt] (c) at (3,.5){};
  \node[red pt] (d) at (2,2.2){};
  \node[fit=(a)(b)(c)(d),draw=blue]{};

  % second case: fitting arbitrary path
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=bb]
    \draw[red] (4,1) to[bend right] (6,1) -- (5,2);
  \end{scope}
  \node[fit=(bb),draw=blue]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Now, I want to make the same things **within a rotated picture**!

My two questions:

1. In my first case (some nodes), I have to add `rotate` option to my fitting node (as `rotate` option does not rotate nodes). **How to find automatically the correct value for this option (eg: the angle between current coordinate system and canvas coordinate system)?**
2. In my second case (arbitrary paths), I can compute local bounding box but globally aligned. **How to compute local bounding box locally aligned of an arbitrary path ?**

Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{
  red pt/.style={circle,minimum size=3pt,fill=red,inner sep=0},
  every picture/.style={line width=1pt,inner sep=0pt},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=20]
  \draw[gray,line width=.4pt] (0,0) grid (6.5,2.5);
  % first case: fitting some nodes
  \node[red pt] (a) at (.5,.5){};
  \node[red pt] (b) at (.5,2){};
  \node[red pt] (c) at (3,.5){};
  \node[red pt] (d) at (2,2.2){};
  % how to find the good value for rotate (here 20)?
  \node[rotate=20,fit=(a)(b)(c)(d),draw=blue]{};

  % second case: fitting arbitrary path
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=bb]
    \draw[red] (4,1) to[bend right] (6,1) -- (5,2);
  \end{scope}
  % how to find bounding box locally aligned ?
  \node[rotate=20,rotate fit=-20,fit=(bb),draw=blue]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Pour moi, c'est un bug

Comment: The translation for the above comment is "For me, this is a bug".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** I finally found a solution myself... but I can not give me my own bounty. ;-)

I define three styles:

1. `memoize points` names each point of a path (with help of `memoizepoints` counter) and cumulates these names into a global macro (its argument).
2. `cont memoize points` is the same as `memoize points`, but without resetting the global macro (its argument).
3. `init memoize points` resets the global macro (its argument) and the `memoizepoints` counter.

Here is the preamble:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,intersections,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
```

The `memoizepoints` counter and the three styles:

```
\newcounter{memoizepoints}
\tikzset{
  init memoize points/.code={\xdef#1{}\setcounter{memoizepoints}{0}},  
  cont memoize points/.style={postaction={
      decorate,decoration={show path construction,
        moveto code={},
        lineto code={
          \foreach \coord in {\tikzinputsegmentfirst,\tikzinputsegmentlast}{
            \addtocounter{memoizepoints}{1}
            \coordinate(memoizepoints-\arabic{memoizepoints}) at (\coord);
            \xdef#1{#1 (memoizepoints-\arabic{memoizepoints})}
          }
        },
        curveto code={
          \foreach \coord in {\tikzinputsegmentfirst,\tikzinputsegmentsupporta,%
            \tikzinputsegmentsupportb,\tikzinputsegmentlast}{
            \addtocounter{memoizepoints}{1}
            \coordinate(memoizepoints-\arabic{memoizepoints}) at (\coord);
            \xdef#1{#1 (memoizepoints-\arabic{memoizepoints})}
          }
        },
        closepath code={
          \foreach \coord in {\tikzinputsegmentfirst,\tikzinputsegmentlast}{
            \addtocounter{memoizepoints}{1}
            \coordinate(memoizepoints-\arabic{memoizepoints}) at (\coord);
            \xdef#1{#1 (memoizepoints-\arabic{memoizepoints})}
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
  memoize points/.style={init memoize points=#1,cont memoize points=#1},
}
```

Then an example followed by its code:

[image]

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=30,inner sep=0pt,line width=1pt]
  \tikzset{
    pt/.style={circle,minimum size=3pt,fill=#1,inner sep=0},
    red pt/.style={pt=red},
  }
  \draw[gray,line width=.4pt] (0,0) grid (9.5,5.5);
  % first case: fitting some nodes
  \node[red pt] (a) at (.5,.5){};
  \node[red pt] (b) at (.5,2){};
  \node[red pt] (c) at (3,.5){};
  \node[red pt] (d) at (2,2.2){};
  \begin{scope}[transform shape]
    \node[fit=(a)(b)(c)(d),draw=blue]{};
  \end{scope}

  % second case: fitting arbitrary path
  \draw[red,memoize points=\allpoints] (4,1) to[bend right] (6,1) -- (5,2);
  \begin{scope}[transform shape]
    \node[fit=\allpoints,draw=blue]{};
  \end{scope}

  % another example of fitting arbitrary path
  \draw[red,memoize points=\allpoints] (8,1.2) circle ();
  \begin{scope}[transform shape]
    \node[fit=\allpoints,draw=blue]{};
  \end{scope}

  % another example of fitting arbitrary paths
  \begin{scope}[yshift=2cm]
    \draw[red,memoize points=\allpoints]
    plot[domain=4:8,samples=100] (\x,{2+sin(3 * \x r)});
    \draw[red,cont memoize points=\allpoints]
    plot[domain=4:8,samples=100] (\x,{2.1+cos(3 * \x r)});
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[transform shape]
    \node[fit=\allpoints,draw=blue]{};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I can delete my answer if you like if the bounty is giving problems. I still didn't have the chance to have a look at it.

Comment: @percusse Don't delete your answer: it provides a half of the answer! The bounty is not a problem. ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Am I missing the point? `transform shape` and resetting the rotation seems like a solution.

---

EDIT: I hope this time I got your point. If not, I would really appreciate explaining in terms of rotated rectangles and shapes, instead of *local* and *global* which are relative terminology with respect to the rotated Tikz picture environment.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\tikzset{
  pt/.style={circle,minimum size=3pt,fill=#1,inner sep=0},
  red pt/.style={pt=red},
  green pt/.style={pt=green},
  every picture/.style={line width=1pt,inner sep=0pt},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=20]
  \draw[gray,line width=.4pt] (0,0) grid (6.5,2.5);
  % first case: fitting some nodes
  \node[red pt] (a) at (.5,.5){};
  \node[red pt] (b) at (.5,2){};
  \node[red pt] (c) at (3,.5){};
  \node[red pt] (d) at (2,2.2){};
  \begin{scope}[transform shape]
    \node[fit=(a)(b)(c)(d),draw=blue]{};
  \end{scope}
\pgfgettransform{\currtrafo}     %Save the current trafo 

  % second case: fitting arbitrary path
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=bb]
\pgftransformresetnontranslations % Now there is no rotation and it doesn't know 
                                  % things are going to be rotated
\begin{scope}                     % We open a new scope and restore the outer trafo
\pgfsettransform{\currtrafo}      % inside the scope

\draw[red] (4,1) to[bend right] (6,1) -- (5,2);  % Draw anything
\end{scope}                                      % Now the trafo is reset again

\node[fit=(bb),draw=blue]{};     % Externally it doesn't know the content is
                                 % rotated or not

  \end{scope}                    % Back to original trafo.
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You give me a solution for my first question. But the second bounding box is always globally aligned. I would like this box is _locally_ aligned.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify my request.

Comment: I think I missed it again. you want the blue rectangle rotated too right?

Comment: Yes: the two blue rectangles should be parallel and the second one should fit the red path.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I've read the `local bounding box` code. It's really difficult to get into it since the node is hardcoded and rotations are a bit tricky. I'll have a more thorough whenever I have the chance and probably patch that macro. It would probably require to draw the path twice.